# angular translate doesn't refresh translation in controller when I change language

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have problem with changing language in controller. When I choose another language, the value in templates change correct translations but translations in controller are still the same.
How can I resolve this problem?

I use `useStaticFilesLoader`.

```
.config(function($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'lang/',
    suffix: '.json'
  });

$translate(['safemode_title','safemode_message','server_error']).then(function (translations) {
  $scope.safemode_title = translations.safemode_title;
  $scope.safemode_message = translations.safemode_message;
  $scope.serverError = translations.server_error;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to listen on the [`$translateChangeStart`](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/18_events) event, so you'll be able to understand when user change the language.

So, change your code to:

```
$rootScope.$on('$translateChangeStart', function (event, a) {
       $translate(['safemode_title','safemode_message','server_error']).then(function (translations) {
            $scope.safemode_title = translations.safemode_title;
            $scope.safemode_message = translations.safemode_message;
            $scope.serverError = translations.server_error;
      });
});
```

for ng-translate (and the filter too) you don't need this listener because it does it automagically for you.

Obiviously, remember to inject `$rootScope` dependency.

Comment: I used '$translateChangeSuccess' instead, served the purpose though. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

It work enough good because when click other language than default language doesn't change. But when I back to default lang then translation is changed to other than default .